# subtracting two datetime variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

How can i get total number of hours between two datetime variable?

```
date1=1/1/2011 12:00:00

date2=1/3/2011 13:00:00
datetime date1 ;

datetime date2;

int hours=(date1.date2).hours;
```

the output is "1" but i want the total hour difference between two date i.e 49hours

thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`TotalHours`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalhours.aspx) instead of [`Hours`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.hours.aspx). Note that the result is a `double` - you can just cast it to `int` to get the *whole* number of hours. (Check what behaviour you want if the result is negative though...)

From the docs for `Hours`:

> **Property Value:** The hour component of the current TimeSpan structure. The return value ranges from -23 through 23

You don't want the hour *component* - you want the whole time span, expressed in hours.

Comment: thanks Jon.In the database datetime type value is in AM PM format how can i convert this to 24 hour format or i will get the correct result without converting it

Comment: @saurabh: That's a completely different question - a matter of fetching the data properly to start with. You shouldn't be fetching it as a string at all, but we can't see any of your code used to access it. I suggest you start a new question if you can't work out how to make your database provider give you a `DateTime` instead of a string.

Answer (score 4):

```
int hours = (int) (date2 - date1).TotalHours;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
        DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2011, 1, 1, 12, 0, 0);
        DateTime date2 = new DateTime(2011, 1, 3, 13, 0, 0);
        TimeSpan ts = date2 - date1;

        double hours = ts.TotalHours;
```